# How to resolve docker connectivity after reboot on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I rebooted my Mac for the first time in a while. Afterwards, docker was unusable because of an error about certificates: "x509: certificate is valid for 192.168.99.103, not 192.168.99.100".

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate certificates:

```
$ docker-machine regenerate-certs
```

HT to [this blog post](https://shekhargulati.com/2016/05/27/docker-machine-error-unable-to-query-docker-version/)